# JQM (jQueryMobile) HTML5 pattern validation with Alternate button type (Not Submit)

Tags: jquery, html, validation, jquery-mobile

Using HTML5 Pattern for form field validation, how does one stop a submission if the form is invalid? Maybe I should ask, how does one create a custom valid/invalid form handler?

[Documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/api/methods.html) on the changePage()

```
$('#form-submit-button').click( function() {
    event.preventDefault(); // This is undefined                    

        // This submits my form and values via ajax, handles page transition
    $.mobile.changePage({
        url: 'request.php?page=one', 
        type: 'post', 
        data: $('form#test_form').serialize()
    },'slide',false,false);
});
```

Example HTML Form Field

```
<input type="text" 
       name="first_name" 
       id="first_name" 
       placeholder="First Name*" 
       pattern="[\w .-]" 
       required />
```

Example HTML Button (Not Submit type)

```
<input type="button" 
       data-theme="z" 
       data-icon="forward" 
       data-inline="true" 
       name="form-submit-button" 
       id="form-submit-button" 
       value="Next Step"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2011/01/html5-form-field-validation.html

According to this, it shouldn't let you submit your form till it validates.